# Element-wise operation of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to average element-wise of three columns with different lengths from three different dataframes in Pandas. For example:

**df_1:**

```
c1 | c2 | c3
0  | 1  | 2
1  | 2  | 3
2  | 3  | 4
```

**df_2:**

```
c1 | c2 | c3
1  | 2  | 3
1  | 2  | 3
1  | 2  | 3
```

**df_3:**

```
c1 | c2 | c3
3  | 2  | 1
1  | 2  | 3
3  | 2  | 1
```

I want to average each element of c3, and save it in a new **df_4**:

```
c1 | c2 | c3
3  | 2  | (2+3+1)/3
1  | 2  | (3+3+3)/3
3  | 2  | (4+3+1)/3
```

I've tried the following which only return NaN values:

```
df_1_c3 = df_1.loc[:,'c3']
df_2_c3 = df_2.loc[:,'c3']
df_3_c3 = df_3.loc[:,'c3']


adc_avg = pd.DataFrame((df_1_c3 + df_2_c3 + df_3_c3 )/3)
```

Comment: c1,c2 columns of df_4 will be same as df_3?

Comment: @IoaTzimas The lengths of c1, c2, and c3 will be different. The resulting column length in df_4 should then equal the longest column length of c3 between df_1, df_2, and df_3.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (given your description, i consider that c1,c2 columns of df_4 are same with df_3):

```
df_4=df_3.copy()
df_4['c3']=[sum(i)/3 for i in zip(df_1.c3, df_2.c3, df_3.c3)]
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the lengths of df_1, df_2, df_3 are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can take 3 columns, make df and mean along axis 1:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': df1['c3'], 'B': df2['c3'],'C': df3['c3']}).mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: This returns a dataframe with only a single column of the mean values. I want the original shape with all other data to transfer over to df_4.